# Chronology - year in first item

Tags: numbering

In the following `chronology` example, how should it be written, when I need number of year in first comma? In my case I need 1980 to show.

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP (copied from edit of now-deleted post by OP):

Stephan Lukasczyk --> Thanks. Here is all needed LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chronology}

\begin {document}
    \begin{chronology}[5]{1980}{2015}{3ex}{\textwidth}
        \event{1984}{first}
        \event[1985]{1986}{two}
        \event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{three}
    \end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: This is clear. I posted only part of my latex file. Problem it's display on this image: http://s11.postimg.org/srbt1sn4j/exam.jpg

Comment: The `chronology` package should be used with care or should be rewritten. Indeed, the author defines latex counters and lengths inside the environment! Therefore, if you use the chronology environment more than once in a document, you have several errors "command already defined".

Comment: The example doesn't compile correctly for me, and I've no real idea what is wanted. As it stands, this is I'm afraid 'unclear'.